# Not able to get photo via API, which returns 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I tried to retrieve a Photo using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), it worked well using the sample account.

But when I sign in with my own account, it was broken.

When I request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/{Id}/photo/$value
```

It returnes:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ad665ca9-9585-4f7a-9dd1-803061d8baba",
            "date": "2018-10-09T15:55:54"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know the reason, it confused me.

Comment: Do you have an mailbox provisioned for your account?

Comment: what does the mailbox provisioned mean? My account is my company office email  address.

Comment: Did you set your photo for your email account?

Comment: I want to get my contacts' photos, not my own photo

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. Did you set the photo for the contact?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't set the photo for the contact before, after I set the photo, I can get it now. But there is another question, the contact members have their photos already, but I can't get that photo. I need to use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/photo to get that photo, but I can't get {user id} from /contacts

Comment: As my understand, the photo of the contact is different from the user’s own photo. The contact is your resource, and the user’s own photo belongs to the user. I think we should distinguish between these two types of photos.

Comment: If you can get the email of the user, I think you can use `/users/{userPrincipalName}/photo/$value` to get the photo. The premise is that this user is in your organization.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! Yes, I confused with the contact's photo and the user's photo.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `/v1.0/me/contacts/{id}/photo/$value` will only return a photo is one exists (i.e. a photo was added to the Contact in Outlook). If no photo was added, it will return an `HTTP 404 - Not Found` exception.

Rather than handling the exception, you can test for the existence of a photo by calling `/v1.0/me/contacts/{id}/photo/` first. If a photo was attached. this will return the metadata for the attached photo (`mediaContentType`, `height`, `width`). If the results come back empty then you know there isn't a photo available.

Keep in mind that Outlook itself pulls profile photos from multiple places. For example, if there isn't an image attached to a Contact and they're part of the same organization, Outlook will attempt to pull the photo from the Contact's account. You can replicate this functionality so long as you have requested the scope `User.ReadBasic.All`.

Together, the process would be something like this:

1. Call `/v1.0/me/contacts/{id}/photo/`
2. If an image exists, call `/v1.0/me/contacts/{id}/photo/$value` to retrieve the image. If not, continue on.
3. Using the `emailAddress` from the Contact, call `/v1.0/users/{emailAddress}/photo`
4. If an image exists, call  `/v1.0/users/{emailAddress}/photo/$value` to retrieve the image. If not, there isn't an image available.

Comment: Thank you very much! But there's a question, as the emailAddresses is an array(EmailAddress collection) from the Contact, I don't know which one is the current userPrincipalName for the target user.

Comment: Unless there is a known pattern for the org, you really don't. Your only option is to iterate through the list and check each address.